# Mathematics of Names

Tags: mathematics, knowledge

If

THOMAS X ABRAHAM = ALEXANDER

ALEXANDER X THOMAS = ANDREW

ANDREW X ABRAHAM = BENJAMIN

BENJAMIN / THOMAS = ?

Choose from 1 ABRAHAM 2 ANDREW 3 ULYSSES 4 GEORGE

Comment: This puzzle would be a great contribution to this month's [MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles) - a prime example of a puzzle easily solvable on a mobile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> 3 **ULYSSES**

As in each case, the names represent...

> ...**people on US banknotes** of particular denominations.
>
>  GEORGE (Washington) on the \$1 bill;
>  THOMAS (Jefferson) on the \$2 bill;
>  ABRAHAM (Lincoln) on the \$5 bill;
>  ALEXANDER (Hamilton) on the \$10 bill;
>  ANDREW (Jackson) on the \$20 bill;
>  ULYSSES (S. Grant) on the \$50 bill;
>  BENJAMIN (Franklin) on the \$100 bill.

Substituting these in to our equations gives:

> THOMAS (2) X ABRAHAM (5) = ALEXANDER (10)
>  ALEXANDER (10) X THOMAS (2) = ANDREW (20)
>  ANDREW (20) X ABRAHAM (5) = BENJAMIN (100)

So...

> BENJAMIN (100) / THOMAS (2) = ULYSSES (50)